# Get notification before expiry date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get notification before three months of the expiry date for a product. expiry_date column is storing as VARCHAR (storing month and year) in DB.

```
<select name="month">
  <?php
   $months = array (

 1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb',3=>'Mar',4=>'Apr',5=>'May',6=>'Jun',7=>'Jul',8=>'Aug',9=>'Sep',10=>'Oct',11=>'Nov',12=>'Dec');
   ?>
  <option value="">Select Month</option>
   <?php
   foreach ($months as $key=>$value) {
   echo '<option name="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
   }
  ?>
 </select>

 <select name="year">
 <?php
$Start_year=date('Y');
 $end_Year=$Start_year+10;
 $yearArray = range($Start_year,$end_Year);
?>
<option value="">Select Year</option>
 <?php
foreach ($yearArray as $key=>$value) {
echo '<option name="'. $key .'">'. $value .'</option>';
 }
 ?>
</select>
```

If I run this query then it is returning array(0) { } . Someone please help me to find out where I'm wrong

```
$futureDate = date('Y M', strtotime("+3 months"));


SELECT * FROM items WHERE expiry_date>$futureDate
```

Comment: Try to use ISO-8601 dates: `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is missing a day number.

Comment: I can't use date here

Comment: What is `expiry_date` if not a date?

Answer (score 0):

You need convert your VARCHAR to DATE.

**expiry_date** need day "Y m 01". In the MySQL use CONCAT " 01" because ***str_to_date*** requiere day.

**$futureDate** need day, add day in PHP or CONCAT in MySQL. 
This query work fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM `test`
WHERE date_format(str_to_date(CONCAT(expiry_date, ' 01'), '%Y %m %d'), '%Y %m') > date_format(str_to_date('$futureDate', '%Y %m %d'), '%Y %m')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

In my database, table *test* has 2 columns, *id* and *expiry_date* VARCHAR eg "2017 01"

Answer (score 0):

In your post you say

> expiry_date column is storing as VARCHAR

which means, in your query,

> SELECT * FROM items WHERE expiry_date>$futureDate

you are trying to make a date comparison between a VARCHAR value and a DATE value since you define $futureDate as DATE,

> $futureDate = date('Y M', strtotime("+3 months"));

which will not work. Both will have to be DATE formatted values. You need to convert your VARCHAR to DATE for comparison.

For example:

```
$expiry_as_date = $year . '-' . $month . '-01';
$new_expiry_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($expiry_as_date));

SELECT * FROM items WHERE $new_expiry_date>$futureDate
```